# NaN warning with fitting a zero inflated negative binomial model

Tags: r, database, data-modeling

I am trying to fit a zero inflated negative binomial model to a dataset of complaints and some predictors for them. When trying a regular negative binomial, it works fine, however when making it a zero inflated negbin model, it returns NaN values for (two predictor variables: hours and visits) the SE and p-values in the summary of the model.

```
Warning: NaNs produced
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = complaints ~ visits + gender + revenue + residency + 
    hours, data = comp, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.07975 -0.65173 -0.24077  0.08785  3.31293 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.7050283  1.4261221   2.598  0.00938 ** 
visits       0.0022846        NaN     NaN      NaN    
genderM      0.5783319  0.3036332   1.905  0.05682 .  
revenue     -0.0174033  0.0043892  -3.965 7.34e-05 ***
residencyY  -0.1785727  0.3117556  -0.573  0.56678    
hours       -0.0029508  0.0007413  -3.980 6.88e-05 ***
Log(theta)   0.5487658        NaN     NaN      NaN    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 22.08077    4.43783   4.976 6.51e-07 ***
visits       0.01180        NaN     NaN      NaN    
genderM      0.26974    1.55676   0.173  0.86244    
revenue     -0.11795    0.01141 -10.339  < 2e-16 ***
residencyY   4.56503    1.45564   3.136  0.00171 ** 
hours       -0.01931        NaN     NaN      NaN    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 1.7311 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 52 
Log-likelihood: -127.2 on 13 Df
```

I saw a similar question with an answer about complete separation, however there is no predictor that perfectly separates 0 and non zero values (atleast what ive seen). Below is a sample of what some of the zero values and their predictors are like (variables in the table are in order of visits, complaints, residency, gender, revenue and hours):

```
201   3374          0         Y      M 255.6324 1657.8924
211   1555          0         Y      M 342.8607 1212.1892
221   2185          0         Y      M 294.5911  932.0161
231    972          0         Y      M 311.6149 1070.7129
241   1566          0         Y      M 260.6672 1707.1469
251   2574          0         Y      M 259.4384 1449.8738
261   2390          0         N      F 219.9528 1759.5416
271   2445          0         N      F 243.4169 1156.7693
281   3077          0         N      F 224.2506 1114.2919
291   2908          0         N      F 257.8778 1065.6133
301   3745          0         N      F 246.1194 2269.0726
```

So i ask what could be the issue here, and what could be some ways to solve it?

Edit:   I tried re-scaling the visits variable, dividing it by 10, as it was quite large (in the 1000's). This actually got rid of the NaN error values. However if i do this, would i have to make further changes to the model/data to ensure consistency?

Comment: Did you notice the warnings you received? You should add them to your question. NB, 13 Df is not large, try removing gender.

Comment: @jay.sf i added the warning to the top of output, just says 'NaNs produced'